# Foreach row, update another table row if exist else insert a new record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I have a query which returns a number of rows.

In following code, one `EnrollmentId` can have multiple `StudentId`s.

```
SELECT 
    [StudentId]
    , [ennrollmentId]
    , [Name]
    , [StartDate]
    , [Enddate]
FROM 
    [Enrollements]
WHERE 
    [ennrollmentId] = @ennrollmentId;
```

Now I want to insert `StudentId`, `EnrollemntId`, `StartDate` and `EndDate` into a new table with these rules, if no row exists for `StudentId` and `EnrollmentId`; if such a row already exists, then update the `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

I wrote following query:

```
INSERT INTO [AnotherTable]
    SELECT *
    FROM [Enrollements]
    WHERE [enrollmentId] = @enrollmentId;  

-- I have enrollmentId as stored procedure parameter
```

But this always inserts a new record, it does not update.

Comment: The instruction to use for this is [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Docs are a bit overwhelming but look at example A.

Comment: Have you tried triggers?

Comment: I strongly recommend against complicating the schema with triggers for such a simple upsert operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the non-merge solution

```
-- Do the update FIRST, because if you INSERT first, then afterwards ALL records will match

UPDATE e1 set [StartDate]=e2.[StartDate],[Enddate]=e2.[Enddate]
    FROM [Enrollements] e1
    INNER JOIN [Enrollements] e2 on e2.[ennrollmentId]=e1.[ennrollmentId] and e2.[StudentId]=e1.[StudentId]

INSERT INTO [AnotherTable]
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM [Enrollements] e1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Enrollements] e2
        WHERE e2.[ennrollmentId]=e1.[ennrollmentId] and e2.[StudentId]=e1.[StudentId]
    )
```

Comment: how about adding a @@rowcount after first statement, and the second will run only if @@rowcount=0

Comment: Correct for one row. But, the presence of a @variable in OPs query does not imply there's only one row, maybe he has a cursor, or just did it for test purposes.

Answer (score 0):

-- Update the row if it exists.

```
UPDATE at
SET at.StartDate= en.StartDate
, at.EndDate = en.EndDate -- Edited: "," in SQL Server in place of "AND"
FROM [AnotherTable] at
join [Enrollements] en 
ON (en.[ennrollmentId] = at.[ennrollmentId] AND en.[ennrollmentId] = @ennrollmentId)
```

-- Insert the row if the UPDATE statement failed.

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0 )  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO [AnotherTable]
    SELECT *
    FROM [Enrollements]
    WHERE [enrollmentId] = @enrollmentId; -- EDITED: updated the table,column name
END
```

Comment: This query is buggy . There can not be and AND on Update SET

Comment: That's a syntactical issue (considering SQL Server). You can just correct this by replacing "AND" with ","  in SQL Server. 

Though "AND" works fine in MySQL.

Comment: @Simsons : I think people here looking for Ideas about solutions of a problem but not to look for syntactical issue. does not make sense to down vote for this reason.

Comment: Look at the Update statement. Not sure from where Production Unit measure  and Producion came into!! It looks completely irrelevant to the question.I can undesratnd if it's just one syntax error, but in this case , answer needs quite a bit improvement . Heis the guideline, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer